# What packages do I need to install?

Tags: .net-core

I've just installed a new webapp with Angular and .net core. I needed CORS so I installed Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors. Now I'm getting version mismatch and having some problems understanding what needs to be installed, comming from the full Visual Studio down to VS Code :-)

```
...\angularnet\angularnet.csproj : error NU1107: Version conflict detected for Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions. Install/reference Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions 2.2.0 directly to project angularnet to resolve this issue.
...\angularnet\angularnet.csproj : error NU1107:  angularnet -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors 2.2.0 -> Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions (>= 2.2.0)
...\lafa\angularnet\angularnet.csproj : error NU1107:  angularnet -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.1 -> Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions (>= 2.1.1 && < 2.2.0).
```

I've already tried to installed Abstractions by

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions -v 2.2.0
```

The problem might I installed Cors by `dotnet add package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors -v 2.2.0` which requires different packages versions. Is there a tool to downgrade to common version versions that everything works on, or upgrade?